# asp.net image source from ftp address

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, ftp, ftpwebrequest

Using C# ASP.Net and visual Studio 2012 ultimate.

I've re-used some code from my form. to download an image from an ftp server.

```
public class FTPdownloader
{
    public Image Download(string fileName, string ftpServerIP, string ftpUserID, string ftpPassword)
    {
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
        Image tmpImage = null;
        try
        {
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + fileName));
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
            Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            tmpImage = Image.FromStream(ftpStream);

            ftpStream.Close();
            //outputStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return tmpImage;
    }
}
```

Works great and all I do is call it like this on my form.

```
imgPart.Image = ftpclass.Download("" + "" + ".jpg", "address/images", "user", "pass");
```

Now this works great for winforms. My new project is an asp.net webform. I need it to do the same thing.
I have re-used this code and seems ok, but when i call the method to img.Image i find img.Image does not exist in asp.net. 
Basically im returning an image and the closest thing i can find is a Img.ImageUrl which of course is a string.

So im Hoping this is a slight change to this code something in the call im missing (new to asp.net ).

Any help would be great. Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you have `using System.Drawing` in your references at the top of your file?

Comment: yep referencing it at the top sorry i didnt put that in

Comment: What errors do you get when you try to compile the code?

Comment: Well like i said img.Image doesnt exist, ImageUrl exist but its a string, my method returns an image so i suppose there would be a "cannot convert image to string ..blah..blah..".

Comment: Remove the part `ImageUrl` and set it back to `Image`, it needs to read what it should be. Where are you declaring `imgPart`, instead of `Image imgPart` try setting `System.Drawing.Image imgPart` so we know for sure you don't have a conflicting Image class

Comment: How do you plan to use this image in asp.net? Show it on page? Write it to disk? Write it to database?

Comment: setting this in asp.net as an image control, (dragged and dropped in the form ).

Comment: simply show the image on the page

Comment: It is probably conflicting with `System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Image`

Comment: Have you included `System.Drawing and` `System.Drawing.Drawing2D` namespaces

Comment: ive included system.drawing only not system.drawing.drawing2d

Comment: @satindersingh They won't need System.Drawing.Drawing2d the issue is a conflict between the System.Drawing.Image and System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Image which are both in scope.

Comment: @StevenSmith Did you get this issue sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a conflict between the `System.Drawing.Image` returned by your download function and the Image control (`System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Image`) of ASP.NET.

You can simplify the issue, by modifying your FTP download function slightly, so that it downloads and save the file ready for use by your Image web control.

Change your download function to:

```
private void Download(string fileName, string ftpServerIP, string ftpUserID, string ftpPassword, string outputName)
{
    using(WebClient request = new WebClient())
    {
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
        byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(string.Format("ftp://{0}{1}", ftpServerIP, filename));

        using(FileStream file = File.Create(Server.MapPath(outputName)))
        {
            file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

The you can use this code to get your image:

```
// Download image
ftpclass.Download("/images/myimage.jpg", "server-address", "user", "pass", "/mysavedimage.jpg");

// Now link to the image
imgPart.ImageUrl = "/mysavedimage.jpg";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You might want to skip the Image and use `byte[] fileData = reqFTP.DownloadData(yourPath)`. I see no use to creating a  `System.Drawing.Image` here